# How to obtain inheritance in sequelize models

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am running a Node.js service with sequelize. I have 4 different types of users, all share some of the same attributes like name, password etc. and all have user-role specific attributes.

Currently, I have all 4 models defined as separate models. This gives code duplication and multiple calls to the database if I want to retrieve all users.

How can I obtain a form of inheritance with sequelize? 
I would like to achieve something like this:

[image: ER DB diagram]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve your ERD above, you can simply Associate each Role **model** `Instructor`, `Student`, `Administrator`, `Janitor` to the main `User` **model** using the Sequelize **Associations**, it's very flexible to define `foreignKeys`, `targetKeys` and `sourceKey`, take a look at the Association part of Sequelize documentation over [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html).

I'm not really sure what specific entities relationship type this would be (meaning `belongsTo`, `belongsToMany`, ..etc) but according to your diagram it is a `hasOne` relationship.

Comment: Thanks @Mohdule. I ended up doing as you suggested and defined my foregin keys like this "db.admins.belongsTo(db.users, { foreignKey: "id", targetKey: "id" });"

Comment: Hi @OhLongJohnJohnson, Can you please elaborate more on how you did solve this?

Comment: I think it does not really answer the question. In other ORMs there are inheritance mecanism where you can handle this either with a single table and a discriminator column or with multiple tables which gets automatically joined.
At the end, you get a User which is either of type Instructor, Student, Administrator or Janitor and have the corresponding fields loaded in root object. You should also be able to know which Class it is instance of (by using instanceof). The question was is it possible with Sequelize or not (seems not ?)